# What determines the time waited for Postgres Transaction Timeout?

Tags: postgresql

What parameter would you change to set how long Postgres waits before deciding a transaction has been interrupted and should be rolled back?

I have a client program that is being frequently terminated in the middle of updating a postgres database.  I need to make sure that postgres catches the loss of connection to the client as quickly as possible and immediately rollsback the transaction.

I have control over the timeout settings on the program, if those matter.  I also have control over the postgres database, but I'm not sure what I should be changing on either if not both.

Comment: Probably the [`statement_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-STATEMENT-TIMEOUT) rather than a "transaction timeout". Or maybe `lock_timeout`

Comment: I'm not sure but this post looks like a duplictate of (or at least is closely related to) [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/164419/63644).

Answer (score 1):

idle_in_transaction_session_timeout (integer)

Releases locks on open transactions that have become idle.

[idle_in_transaction_session_timeout parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-STATEMENT-TIMEOUT)